# How to change a dynamic snippet to a static?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, memory

I am getting out of memory alert in this function, called `500K` times:

```
public void DoStuff(string msg)
{
     rtfTerminal.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                rtfTerminal.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                rtfTerminal.AppendText(msg);
                rtfTerminal.ScrollToCaret();

            }));

}
```

In the global scope I declared:

```
  private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtfTerminal;
```

- I guess I get the out of memory since I do `new EventHandler` each
  call, How can I avoid that?
- Is it reasonable that I get the out of memory due to
  `rtfTerminal.AppendText(msg);`?

Comment: Try adding `GC.Collect` at the end of the method, see if that helps.

Comment: @AntonieBlom that is ***very*** rarely a good thing

Comment: You should NEVER need to call `GC.Collect`. That's bad practice...

Comment: What is the text appended for 500K times? (I mean what is the total text length resulting in the RTB at the end?)

Comment: @Steve it is line per 1ms * 5hours ~ 2 milions * 100 chars = 200 milions

Comment: @MarcGravell I know, but I was only interested whether the error was caused by the GC. By no means way I suggesting he implemented this as the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new EventHandler` is not a massive problem, nor is the anonymous object that you can't really see (but which exists): both of these will be short-lived, i.e. GEN-0 and will virtually free to collect. Additionally, GC will kick in if things start to run low, so that *shouldn't* be a problem. Continually adding text to a `RichTextBox` without limit could be a problem. I would try to avoid that. Files are usually a better option for dumping output from long-running processes.

Ultimately, if that doesn't help: you need to use something like a memory profiler to see where the memory is going.

Answer (score 1):

The out of memory exception may show against the line with the "invoke" call but is almost certainly coming from the add to the richTextBox.

Tick "thrown" against debug->exceptions->CLR Exceptions to see this while debugging.

100 unicode chars every ms should eat up about 686MB an hour, check Available MB in task manager to see if this is the culprit.